# Php - Difference of Date&Time

Tags: php, html

I need to get the difference of two Date with time. I have tried to code but it doesn't work.

**HTML PAGE**

```
<div class="col-xs-3 ">
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="planeddate">
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 ">
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="actualdate">
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 ">
<input type="time" class="form-control" name="planedtime">
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-3 ">
<input type="time" class="form-control" name="actualtime">
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include "connect.php"
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("Your Connection is in error");
$planeddate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['planeddate']));
$actualdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['actualdate']));
$planedtime=$_REQUEST['planedtime'];
$actualtime=$_REQUEST['actualtime'];
$diff =date_diff($actualdate,$planeddate); 
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
$time_diff = $actualtime - $planedtime;
echo $time_diff;
?>
```

I am not getting both date and time differences. Please help me out.
And also calculate the difference for the input type "datetime-local" if possible.

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="datetime">
```

Comment: The element name is same. So please change it or make an array.Like planedtime[]

Comment: also reefer this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
$planeddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['planeddate']));
$actualdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['actualdate']));

$datetime1 = new DateTime($planeddate);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($actualdate);

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');

$time1 = new DateTime('09:00:59');
$time2 = new DateTime('09:01:00');

$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $interval->format('%s second(s)');
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: But i need to get the date from html form. Any idea

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: Thanks Worked. I want the time also in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```html
<?php
$planed_date_time = $_POST['planeddate'].' '.$_POST['planedtime'];
$actual_date_time = $_POST['actualdate'].' '.$_POST['actuatime'];

$planed = new DateTime($planed_date_time);
$actual = new DateTime($actual_date_time);

echo $actual->diff($planed)->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
?>
```